# One ViewModel, multiple views

Tags: wpf, mvvm, caliburn.micro

I am having a hard time getting multiple views to work against 1 viewmodel. I have read [Naming Convention for Multi-View Support](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=View/ViewModel%20Naming%20Conventions&ANCHOR) without getting much out of it, and have tried countless things in the process.

Just to take a simple example. Say I have a ViewModel for People residing in ShellViewModel, which basically contains a list of Person-objects. I want to display them in two different ways in my application.

[image]

What is the correct way to name the Views in this case, and how do I display both views in ShellView?

Comment: Not sure why the close votes and downvote.  Multiple views over a single VM in CM is common.

Comment: Turn debugging on, it will tell you when it can't find a view and where it looked.  Check out View.Context and checkout the HelloScreens example it is an example of multiple views over a single VM.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Anders is correct, there are a number of default conventions for `Caliburn.Micro`, one of them will locate and display `<RootNS>.Views.[<ChildNS>].<ViewTypeName>` for `<RootNS>.ViewModels.[<ChildNS>].<ViewModelTypeName>`.

In your case, for a single `View` (assuming the classes reside in namespaces derived from the folders):

`<RootNS>.Views.PeopleView` would by located and displayed for `<RootNS>.ViewModels.PeopleViewModel`.

For multiple views over the same viewmodel, the convention is that views of format `<EntityName>.<Context>` are displayed for viewmodels of format `<EntityName>[<ViewSuffix>]ViewModel`:

From your example, you could create a new folder named `People`, and inside it, create your views named `Grid` and `List`.

Your namespaces become `<RootNS>.Views.People.Grid` and `<RootNS>.Views.People.List` and, should then be located and displayed for `<RootNS>.ViewModels.PeopleViewModel`.

You typically then display the `Views` in something like a `ContentControl`, choosing the `View` you want to display by setting the `cal:View.Context` property. You'll either hard code the name, if the context isn't going to change in that particular control, or bind to a property which describes what state the `ViewModel` should be displayed as.

e.g.

```
<ContentControl cal:View.Model="{Binding Path=ActiveItem}" 
                cal:View.Context="List" />
```

See the [Multiple Views over the Same ViewModel](http://caliburnmicro.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Screens%2c%20Conductors%20and%20Composition&referringTitle=Documentation) section.

Comment: Glad there was something useful in there :D

Answer (score 4):

As far as I can tell from the documentation you are referring to, you should **not** use *View* in your view name. Name your view classes *People.Grid* and *People.List* instead.

Comment: But, this blog [link](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/01/12/caliburn-micro-part-1-getting-started/) shows step 2, which specifcally says include **ViewModel** in the viewmodel's name